# How to scrape the webpage build with Flutter CanvasKit renderer

Tags: python, web-scraping, canvas, canvaskit

I need to extract data from a website but I found that it was rendered with Flutter Canvaskit renderer. It seems everything I wanted is drawn in the canvas. I have to go through each row, trigger click on a row and then trigger info button on top right which shows the file's attributes and get one of the attribute from there. [refer images]

Is this possible? If so, how? I want to do it in python.

[image: ]]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The CORS issue.

In my case.

1. Use a web proxy like `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/$urlTarget`
2. Scrape the webpage in the back-end, then send the data via API.

I chose method 2 because it is easy to fix when the webpage changes.